# spring data mongodb full text search

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I've got a domain

```
@Document
public @Data class Note {

    @Id
    private String noteId;
    private String owner;
    @TextIndexed
    private String name;
    @TextIndexed
    private String text;
    private List<Tag> tags;
    private LocalDate date;
```

With two indexed fields - `name` and `text`. I want to perform full text search by these fields.

Rest that expects search criteria looks like this

```
@GetMapping("/notes-rest/search/custom")
public List<Note> searchNotes(@RequestParam("criteria") String searchCriteria) {
    LOGGER.info("Attempt to perform full text search by criteria: [{}].", searchCriteria);
    return searchRepository.findNotesByCriteria(searchCriteria);
}
```

I pass it lines like this

```
localhost:8080/notes-rest/search/custom?criteria={'name':'1234', 'text': 'trx'}
```

Repository method that performs full text search looks like this

```
@Repository
public class SearchRepository implements ISearchRepository {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate template;

    @Override
    public List<Note> findNotesByCriteria(String searchCriteria) {
        TextCriteria criteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().matching(searchCriteria);
        Query query = TextQuery.queryText(criteria);
        return template.find(query, Note.class);
    }
}
```

But no matter what I pass, it always returns the whole data from the database

```
[
    {
        "noteId": "594eae353bc51592f432b62e",
        "owner": "xxx",
        "name": "xxx note",
        "text": "My text",
        "tags": [
            {
                "tagId": null,
                "tag": "basic2"
            }
        ],
        "date": [
            1997,
            12,
            15
        ]
    },
    {
        "noteId": "594ea38a3bc5150070d0aed2",
        "owner": "system",
        "name": "system note",
        "text": "My text",
        "tags": [
            {
                "tagId": "594e629b3bc5150f4c869905",
                "tag": "basic"
            }
        ],
        "date": [
            1997,
            12,
            15
        ]
    },
    {
        "noteId": "594ea0ae3bc5150ad88a1dfc",
        "owner": "borland",
        "name": "borland note",
        "text": "My text",
        "tags": null,
        "date": [
            1992,
            12,
            15
        ]
    }
]
```

What is the problem?

Comment: change find call to specify desired fields

Comment: @ScottStensland what do you mean?

Comment: I'm on a bus ... Read https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/

Answer (score 0):

I changed format of my search criteria to `{name:"borl", text: "t"}` and it seems it started to work fine

Comment: Are you sure text fields are indexed correctly and used ?  Text search takes the search term not the search criteria. Something like  `TextCriteria criteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().matching("1234 trx");`